# Basic question on how to get next/previous element in xts

Tags: r, finance, xts

I have a very basic question... Suppose I can get a closing price for specific symbol for current date in an xts object using

```
closePrice<-as.double(Cl(get(symbol))[currentDate])
```

How can I get close price on the trading day one day, two days, three days, ... or n days before/after?

```
closePriceNDaysBefore<-as.double(Cl(get(symbol))[currentDate - n])
```

is not ok...

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Samo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this rather easily, depending on what you mean by 'current date'.

If current date is the last entry (just pulled up to date data), then last and first will help:

```
> x <- xts(1:10, Sys.Date()-0:9)
> x <- xts(1:10, Sys.Date()-0:9)
> x
           [,1]
2011-02-16   10
2011-02-17    9
2011-02-18    8
2011-02-19    7
2011-02-20    6
2011-02-21    5
2011-02-22    4
2011-02-23    3
2011-02-24    2
2011-02-25    1

# gets the last 3 periods (days here)
> last(x,3)  # or last(x, "3 days")
           [,1]
2011-02-23    3
2011-02-24    2
2011-02-25    1

# this would get you the 3rd day back from the end
> first(last(x,3),1)
           [,1]
2011-02-23    3
```

If instead you need the current date to mean something like the date you care about in this particular loop/context, the **which.i=TRUE** argument to the subset will help - as it employes the very same fast ISO lookup, but returns the position(s) that match. That is, it doesn't do the subset.

```
> x[x["2011-02-25", which.i=TRUE] - 0]  # today
           [,1]
2011-02-25    1

> x[x["2011-02-25", which.i=TRUE] - 1]  # yesterday
           [,1]
2011-02-24    2
> x[x["2011-02-25", which.i=TRUE] - 2]  # 2 days ago...
           [,1]
2011-02-23    3

> x[x["2011-02-25", which.i=TRUE] - 3]  # you get the idea ;-)
           [,1]
2011-02-22    4

> x["2011-02-25", which.i=TRUE] 
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data are daily and only include trading days, lag the time series before subsetting.

```
closePriceNDaysBefore <- as.double(lag(Cl(get(symbol)),n)[currentDate])
```

If that doesn't work, please be more specific about your data structure.

Comment: Joshua. Thnx. How to get the next/previous (n days before/after) current date date. So, how to get a date of the xts (not the values). Thnx.

Comment: @Samo: Maybe `?index`?  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: OK. Let me be more clear, I am trying to replicate Monthly End of Month Strategy using Blotter and TTR. The description of the strategy is here http://quantingdutchman.wordpress.com/2010/06/30/strategy-2-monthly-end-of-the-month-meom/ . I guess I am very akward. But, i am calculating which two (or N) ETFs from the list to trade on one day before the last trading day of the month. On the next day (last trading day of the month) I go long this two ETFs. I exit next trading day on the close (if it is an upday) or on the second trading day on the close (after entry). So, I need to know trade days.

Comment: Or, to put it differently, I need a function on xts object that takes as a parameter xts object, myDateOfInterest and number of days (before or after (+/-)) and returns the particular row of xts object. myFunction<-function(Xts, myDateOfInteres, numLagDays) and the result should be one row with date as rowname and a value of interest...

Answer (score 0):

Use which() and match your date string to rownames. Then the result is numeric and can be handled as a numeric index:

```
M <- as.xts(read.table(textConnection(" SPY.Close    mavg      dn.1      up.1 
2010-11-18    119.96 120.713 118.17955 119.99845   
2010-11-19    120.29 120.470 118.33112 120.09688   
2010-11-22    120.19 120.240 118.47911 120.18489   
2010-11-23    118.45 119.924 118.55112 120.20888   
2010-11-24    120.20 119.734 118.63565 120.27635   
") ) )
> M[which(rownames(M)=="2010-11-22"), "SPY.Close"]
[1] 120.19
> M[which(rownames(M)=="2010-11-22")-1, "SPY.Close"]
[1] 120.29
```

Thanks to J. Winchester for pointing out that xts objects produced by the sequential application of getSymbols and Cl functions from quantmod have empty or NULL rownames but that the time() function can access that information and be used as:
`which(as.character(time(M))=="2010-11-22")`

Comment: This will only work if you convert `M` to a `matrix` or `data.frame` first, since xts objects don't have `rownames`.

Comment: I just showed you that it worked with an xts object. If you look at its structure you will see that it has a matrix "core", and furthermore is.matrix() returns TRUE.

Comment: @Dwin: I can't reproduce your results with any CRAN version of xts from the past year. I'm familiar with the structure. I helped write the package.

Comment: I have xts_0.7-5 dated 2010-08-19. I am reporting on the results I describe for the first example in help(as.xts) as well as the example above. I just repeated the test on the example above: is.matrix(M) still returns
[1] TRUE

Comment: For me, is.matrix(M) returns TRUE, but rownames(M) is NULL. But, time(M) returns the date index and the example should work with that. `which(as.character(time(M))=="2010-11-22")`

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to remember that you can shift a vector either direction by taking its tail or head. In your case, append an NA at the start because the first day does not have a "yesterday".

```
M$Prev.Close <- c(NA, head(M$SPY.Close, -1))
```